# How do I reformat a fixed-state/pseudo-readonly SD card?

Tags: sd-card, windows, macos, formatting, reformat

Alright, so this is an ongoing saga of trying to fix my broken SD card. Let me struggle to explain what's wrong with it.

**When copying files to the SD card**

The files are completely corrupted. For instance, have a listen to Body Talk by Robyn:

https://soundcloud.com/nobleuplift/sets/corrupted-body-talk

Some songs are mashups of other songs on my phone, or speed up to 4x speed. We Dance to the Beat takes 17 seconds to play.

**When deleting files from the SD card**

The files/folders will appear deleted up to the point either when the SD card is mounted/unmounted, reformatted, or the phone is restarted.

Yes, you heard me right, **reformatting does not delete any data from my SD card**. It is restored to the state it was in two weeks ago when I first noticed signs of corruption.

On the bright side, I can still listen to anything I copied to the SD card beforehand with no corruption.

**When trying to reformat the SD card by other means**

First, I tried to reformat the SD card using Windows XP. I tried both exFAT and NTFS. exFAT failed immediately, whereas NTFS took about 15 minutes before it said it couldn't do it.

I tried the exact same thing on my MacBook Pro and here are the logs from trying that:

```
===== Monday, 2015 June 8 at 11:43:24 PM Central Daylight Time =====
2015-06-08 23:43:34 -0500: Preparing to erase : “SD64GB”
2015-06-08 23:43:34 -0500:  Partition Scheme: Master Boot Record
2015-06-08 23:43:34 -0500:  1 volume will be created
2015-06-08 23:43:34 -0500:      Name        : “SD64GB”
2015-06-08 23:43:34 -0500:      Size        : 63.86 GB
2015-06-08 23:43:34 -0500:      File system : ExFAT

2015-06-08 23:43:34 -0500: Unmounting disk
2015-06-08 23:43:34 -0500: Creating the partition map
2015-06-08 23:43:34 -0500: Waiting for the disks to reappear
2015-06-08 23:43:34 -0500: Formatting disk2s1 as ExFAT with name SD64GB
2015-06-08 23:43:34 -0500: Reformatting existing ExFAT volume
Volume name      : SD64GB
Partition offset : 0 sectors (0 bytes)
Volume size      : 124733440 sectors (63863521280 bytes)
Bytes per sector : 512
Bytes per cluster: 131072
FAT offset       : 2048 sectors (1048576 bytes)
# FAT sectors    : 4096
Number of FATs   : 1
Cluster offset   : 6144 sectors (3145728 bytes)
# Clusters       : 487216
Volume Serial #  : 5bc0a34d
Bitmap start     : 2
Bitmap file size : 60902
Upcase start     : 3
Upcase file size : 5836
Root start       : 4

2015-06-08 23:43:34 -0500: Mounting disk
2015-06-08 23:43:34 -0500: Could not mount disk2s1 with name (null) after erase
2015-06-08 23:43:34 -0500: Erase complete.
2015-06-08 23:43:34 -0500:
```

So... yeah... Anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: The card may very well be broken. If you have a linux or a mac handy, try `dd` or `badblocks` command to do an image of the card or scan it to see if any errors are detected. There are lots of how-to's on this topic.

Comment: Does the card have to be mounted to run those? When I tried to mount disk2s1, OS X told me it could not mount it.

Comment: No, you don't. This is block-level operation while mounting is filesystem-level.

Comment: Alright, I'll try again using my MacBook when I get home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to send a support request to SanDisk, who told me to break the chip in half and then send it back to them since it is still under warranty.

http://kb.sandisk.com/app/ask/p/557,785,786,2158